# In Pandas, why does the groupby 'key' column disappear in this scenario

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code...which for some reason results in the 'key' column disappearing. I have also noticed other times when the key column seems to 'randomly' disappear. I am trying to isolate the cases, this is one.

I am usinng pandas version 0.20.1

```
DF = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['b', 3]], columns = ['G', 'N'])
groupByObj = DF.groupby('G')
print groupByObj.get_group('b')
groupByObj.sum()
print groupByObj.get_group('b')
```

The first `print groupByObj.get_group('b')` results in:

```
   G  N
1  b  2
2  b  3
```

The second `print groupByObj.get_group('b')` results in:

```
   N
1  2
2  3
```

Why does the 'key' column ('G') disappear after running `groupByObj.sum()`

Comment: Additional info: It does not happen if `as_index=False` is passed when the object is created `groupByObj = DF.groupby('G', as_index=False)`.

Comment: This looks like a bug, it seems that the aggregation operation somehow mutates or introduces some kind of caching operation on the `groupby` object. This happens on my machine using pandas version `0.20.3` I'd post this as an issue on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues). This occurs once you call `sum` and then `get_group`. To me it looks like the first output is incorrect, the `G` column should become the index but it doesn't until the aggregation is performed.

Comment: Looking at this again I think the first output is wrong, the `G` column should form the index, this doesn't seem to happen until you perform the aggregation so `get_group` here isn't doing this correctly

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Pandas, discussed in:

- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12839
- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14013

The latter is still open.

From reading a bit in GitHub, and as mentioned in the comments, it seems that the second output is the wanted behavior, and was obtained in the `sum` case by adding the following line to `pandas.core.groupby._GroupBy#_set_group_selection`:

```
self._reset_cache('_selected_obj')
```

Since this reset happens when calling `sum` (and a few other functions), this G column is still visible on the first `get_group` call. BTW - the reset isn't performed also when calling `mean`, and a few other functions as well. It seems that this bug is a bit more comprehensive than thought, and was not solved by the simple cache reset.